# How to set up Apache to allow direct routing in AngularDart?

Tags: apache, dart, angular-dart

I have a farly simple AngularDart application which does nothing but show two different views. My issue is that I can not browse the non-default route directly (e.g. http://www.example.com/login) as Apache says the requested URL was not found on this server - which is pretty much correct because these routes are virtual, right?

So, my question is: how to I set up Apache correctly? Is there some mod_rewrite rule or anything that can pass the URL to my app? Right now the virtual host is a simple virtual host, no extra sugar.

Any suggestions to solve this issue are welcome!

---

Also, so that we have some foundation to discuss about if needed, here is my routing configuration:

```dart
views.configure({
    'login': ngRoute(
        path: '/login',
        view: 'views/security/login.html'
    ),
    'index': ngRoute(
        path: '/',
        defaultRoute: true,
        view: 'views/index.html'
    )
});
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you've chosen to use ngRoute instead of ui-Router?

Comment: The answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034082 should apply here as well - just replace `index.php` with `index.html`

Comment: @Orane I'm not sure what you mean by `ui-Router`. This is caused by using HTML5 `pushState` instead of URL fragments. `ngRoute` is just an Angular helper function to pass route parameters.