# Angular 2 Routing with Amazon EC2 404 error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to get a deployment of a MEAN stack app using angular2 v1.0.0 beta.3 up and running.  Everything is going well so far except this annoying routing issue that did NOT occur when I deployed to Heroku. However; this is my first experience deploying to ec2 using elastic beanstalk.

When I open up the route at the base route / the page loads as normal and I can use the app as if nothing is wrong. However, if I navigate to a subroute, in my case /client/issue/:id , the state loads, but if I reload the page I will get a 404 ERROR.  In my server.js I have what I thought was a 404 catch app.get('*', loadIndex'), but this does not seem to be the case.  I assume it is an issue with the way ec2 handles routing, but I am not sure.

EDIT

---

It might also be worth noting that I am only getting an error in my /var/log/nginx/error.log file and not the /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log file.

From the error.log file:

```
2016/04/06 15:14:00 [error] 18952#0: *16 open() "/var/app/current/client/Issue/yes/57044092fe1924e77d9049ab" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.31.4.202, server: , request: "GET /client/Issue/yes/57044092fe1924e77d9049ab HTTP/1.1",
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034082/httpd-conf-and-html5-pushstate

Comment: I think that link has a solution that is on the right track, but I am now looking around for an implementation of that in nodejs that is different than I already have.