# angular2 route deep linking in apache

Tags: angular

I made a small angular2 route app. It is working fine while 'npm start'.

But as soon as I deploy it to apache, whenever I try to change route manually by typing in browser address bar, it shows error.

I tried solution given at [Angular2 routing / deep linking not working with Apache 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816025/angular2-routing-deep-linking-not-working-with-apache-404) , but it is still not working while changing route manually.

I made a small screencast of my problem. If anyone can help me.
https://youtu.be/a7oDW3KsYCU

Thanks

[EDIT]
My .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /angulardeploy2/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I modify it.

Comment: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/apache-htaccess-for-html5-push-state-manipulations, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034082/httpd-conf-and-html5-pushstate

Comment: I have edited my question , how can I change my .htaccess file. I have no idea about Apache configuration.

Comment: Sounds more like an Apache question than an Angular question. I'd fix the tag to get attention by the right people.

Comment: I should remove this line `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]`

Comment: Dear @PierreDuc I removed that line, but still on manual page refresh it give error 'Object not found --- 404''

Answer (score 0):

This setting in src/.htaccess should work, provided that mod_rewrite is enabled.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

and do not forget to include .htaccess file in the bundle that gets deployed , you can do that by registering the file as an asset in .angular-cli.json.

```
 "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        ".htaccess"
      ],
```